# Finding percentage of users with certain conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, percentage

Using MySQL, I need to find the percentage of users with >= 30 AverageActiveMinutes AND the percentage of users with < 30 AverageActiveMinutes from a table with the following structure:

| Id | AverageActiveMinutes |
| --- | --- |
| 1503960366 | 37.92 |
| 1644430081 | 2.50 |
| 1844505072 | 0.00 |
| 3977333714 | 19.82 |
| 5553957443 | 97.88 |
| 7086361926 | 47.46 |
| 8792009665 | 1.67 |

I am looking for an output with two columns and one row that looks something like this:

| PercentOver30 | PercentUnder30 |
| --- | --- |
| 42.9 | 57.1 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation. In MySQL:

```
select avg(AverageActiveMinutes > 30) RatioOver30,
   1 - avg(AverageActiveMinutes > 30) RatioUnder30
from mytable
```

Here, MySQL evaluates the predicates once for each row; when the condition is met, it is intepreted as `1` by `avg()` (and conversely `0` when the condition is not met). The average of that gives you the ratio of rows that satisfy the predicate. You can multiply it by `100` if you prefer a percentage.